# How to handle Internal server error (500) on spring rest API to custom the message?

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

I am working on spring rest api and I would like to sure everything is working fine. I would like to log abnormal behaviors database connection error among others, I'm working with couchbase database and I'm getting in the endpoint response for example for this kind of exception: `CouchbaseQueryExecutionException` the next message: `Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors: \n{\"msg\":\"No index available on keyspace kids_club that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.\",\"code\":4000}` and a very long trace.

For this i found a solution on internet that is extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and override handleExceptionInternal method like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static String DEFAULT_VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE = "KC-0020";

    @ExceptionHandler(MiddlewareException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleKidsClubException(MiddlewareException ex) {
        return buildErrorResponse(HttpStatus.valueOf(ex.getHttpStatus()), ex.toError());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceUnavailableException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleServiceUnavailable(ServiceUnavailableException ex) {
        return buildErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleNoFoundElement(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        return buildErrorResponse(NOT_FOUND, ex);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CouchbaseQueryExecutionException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleCouchbaseQueryException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        return buildErrorResponse(BAD_REQUEST, ex);
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to catch any kind of Internal Server Error in this way.
It seems like spring is handle and building the final message to the user. 
Any ideas to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex, WebRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info("Entering into the handleAllException method");
    System.out.println("Exception is : " + ex.getClass());
    ResponseData error = new ResponseData();
    error.setRespCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
    error.setRespMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);



}
```

please try this way below to check whether you are able to catch exception or not.. From the sysout you will get the exact exception. Then you can use that exception to catch any particular exception from that business logic..

Comment: But the thing is that @ControllerAdvice only handle the controller and service issues no the server ones.

Comment: the process is like i m throwing only from the controller class..I am calling service and dao layer but if any exception happend, it catch by @controlleradvice ...and go to the method as per the type of exception.